# Select Test As [text()]

Tags: t-sql

I have inherited this line of code. Normally, I would expect what occurs after the As to be an alias. However, I have never seen an alias in square brackets. Also, I'm not sure what the parens in text() signify? Is text an obsolete data type? Is there any link someone can send me so I can figure out what this means?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider the documentation?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx   Never seen it?  It is how you put a space in an alias.  Did you consider running the statement and see what happens?

Answer (score 6):

The `[text()]` alias is often used in **XML** queries to make the value from a column become the text output in an element:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (FieldText varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('some text'), ('more text')

SELECT FieldText
FROM @Table 
FOR XML PATH('RECORD'), ROOT('ROOT'), TYPE

--<ROOT>
--  <RECORD>
--    <FieldText>some text</FieldText>
--  </RECORD>
--  <RECORD>
--    <FieldText>more text</FieldText>
--  </RECORD>
--</ROOT>

SELECT FieldText as [text()]
FROM @Table 
FOR XML PATH('RECORD'), ROOT('ROOT'), TYPE

--<ROOT>
--  <RECORD>some text</RECORD>
--  <RECORD>more text</RECORD>
--</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, I have never seen an alias in square brackets

It can be, if you are trying to use a keyword/reserveword as your alias name (OR) if you are trying to use a name which has spaces between them like `My Special Alias name`

Using `As [text()]` looks bit weird to me. No it doesn't signifies anything. Alias names are just text literal for better readable name but I would suggest use proper name which increases readability else there is no point in using alias name(s).

Answer (score 1):

It is a little odd, for a field name, but the Brackets are nothing new

```
Declare @Table table (test varchar(25))
Insert into @Table values ('Some Value')

Select Test as [text()] From @Table
```

Returns

```
text()
Some Value
```

Use can use brackets for non-standard field names i.e. [Total Sales]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server formats Alias' in queries in square brackets